# Listview is not receive notification when adapter data changed in fragment

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-listview

Listview data is not refreshing after array list data and adapter data changed.

My code :

```
listView = (ListView) detailsView.findViewById(R.id.settings_fragment_list);
ticketCommentsPriorityData.clear();

        for (int i = 0; i <mTicketData.size(); i++) {
            totalTicketsData =mTicketData.get(i).getTotalTicketsData();

            for (int j = 0; j <mTicketData.get(i).getTotalTicketsData().size(); j++) {

                if (ticketID.equalsIgnoreCase(mTicketData.get(i).getTotalTicketsData().get(j).getTicketID())) {
                    TicketCommentsPriorityData commentsPriorityData = new TicketCommentsPriorityData();
                    String comment =mTicketData.get(i)
                            .getTotalTicketsData().get(j).getComments();
                    String priority =mTicketData.get(i)
                            .getTotalTicketsData().get(j).getPriority();
                    commentsPriorityData.setComments(comment);
                    commentsPriorityData.setPriority(priority);

                    ticketCommentsPriorityData.add(commentsPriorityData);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if (ticketCommentsPriorityData != null
            && ticketCommentsPriorityData.size() > 0) {

        detailListAdapter = new TicketDetailListAdapter(getActivity(),
                R.layout.ticket_list_items, ticketCommentsPriorityData);


                listView.setAdapter(detailListAdapter);

            }
```

Adapter class

```
public class TicketDetailListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<TicketCommentsPriorityData> {

Context context;
ArrayList<TicketCommentsPriorityData> ticketData;
LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
int layoutResourceID;

public TicketDetailListAdapter(Context context,int layoutResourceID,
        ArrayList<TicketCommentsPriorityData> ticketData) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    super(context, layoutResourceID, ticketData);
    this.context = context;
    this.ticketData = ticketData;
    this.layoutResourceID = layoutResourceID;
    layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}


@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ViewHolder viewHolder = null;

    if (convertView == null) {
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(layoutResourceID,
                parent, false);

        viewHolder.ticketID = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.ticket_id);
        viewHolder.ticketDate = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.ticket_date);

        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    } else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    viewHolder.ticketDate.setText(ticketData.get(position).getComments());
    viewHolder.ticketID.setText(ticketData.get(position).getPriority());

    return convertView;

}

class ViewHolder {
    TextView ticketID;
    TextView ticketDate;
}
}
```

Edit #1 :

OnItemClick :

```
   mTicketsListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            String ticketIDList = mTicketData.get(position).getTicketID();

            String createdOn = mTicketData.get(position).getCreatedOn();
            TicketDetailListFragment detailFragment = new TicketDetailListFragment();
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("ticket_id", ticketIDList);
             FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity()
                        .getSupportFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager
                        .beginTransaction();

                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.tickets_details_container,
                        detailFragment);
                fragmentTransaction.commit();
       }
    });
```

my problem was When I tap on parent list item this listview executes and it display details of parent list item.but here if I tap on first item and it's getting first item details and it's displaying correctly.But,if I tap on another items it's displaying always what ever item details comes first into details list it always displaying that data only.

Any one give me a solution.

Comment: Please post your `OnItemClickListener`.

Comment: Are you sure that `ticketID` is being updated correctly in the Fragment?

Comment: yes.I checked it at the time of debugging it's different.

Comment: Do you have a `TicketDetailListFragment` statically declared in your layout? Or are they loaded dynamically?